# Letters only using Jquery Validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I tried every solution from articles [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115372/jquery-validate-plugin-adding-a-custom-validator-to-accept-letters-only),  [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999039/jquery-validation-form-ensure-no-numbers-in-first-and-last-name-input-only-let) , [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44473889/validate-form-field-for-containing-only-letters-using-bootstrap-validator)  yet in my  [sample project](https://information-contact.000webhostapp.com/), I can still enter a number or spec char in the first name field.

**The six+ things I tried:**

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ submitHandler: function(form) { form.submit(); } });

jQuery.validator.addMethod("regex", function(value, element, param) { return value.match(new RegExp("^" + param + "$")); });
var ALPHA_REGEX = "[a-zA-Z]*";

jQuery.validator.addMethod("accept", function(value, element, param) {
  return value.match(new RegExp("." + param + "$"));
});

function isValid(value)
{
  var fieldNum = /^[a-z]+$/i;

  if ((value.match(fieldNum))) {
      return true;
  }
  else
  {
      return false;
  }

}

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({
                  fields: {
            first_name: 
            {
                validators: {
                field: { accept: "[a-zA-Z]+" },
                regex: ALPHA_REGEX,
                 lettersonly:true,
                required: true,
                pattern: "^[a-zA-Z_]*$",
                        stringLength: {
                        min: 2,

                    },
                        notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please supply your first name',
                        callback: function(value, validator, $field) {
                            if (!isValid(value)) {
                              return {
                                valid: false,
                              };
                            }
                            else
                            {
                              return {
                                valid: true,
                              };    

                    }
                }


            },
```

I am sure I am missing something simple or possibly using a slightly outdated jQuery Library? EDIT: I actually just tried using other versions of the library to no success.

Comment: As I understand you use the `ALPHA_REGEX` which is `"[a-zA-Z]*"`. That means a letter zero or more times... am I right? Did you try to set + instead of *?

Comment: Just tried   `var ALPHA_REGEX = "^[a-zA-Z_]*$";`    and  `var ALPHA_REGEX = "[a-zA-Z]+";`  it also did not work.

Comment: And what is the value that you pass to the validation function? (the name you entered)

Comment: I did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115372/jquery-validate-plugin-adding-a-custom-validator-to-accept-letters-only solution but changed the ALPHA_REGEX to + instead of *. I am going to try the solution without the other solutions maybe theres too many "cooks in the kitchen"

Comment: ...if it is + and not * than that article above is wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794162/jquery-validation-plugin-accept-only-alphabetical-characters Think I’m missing the script from this article I found with 76 upvotes. Then you just add letters only. On my phone so will try later...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try your REGEX on some "Regex Matcher".

After you have the right REGEX, make sure you are passing it to your function, and not another one.

Comment: https://regexr.com/  using [a-zA-Z]* found only letters no spec chars so that part is right... using + actually did the same thing so you are both right. Now I see the confusion, ha.

Comment: It's actually not the same, when you use * you will accept empty strings. when you use + you must have at least one character

Comment: I have a min of 2 length set on my inputs (if that’s what you’re referring too). So I cannot accept an empty string though that info is good to know